# Maximo Anywhere 7.6.2 build failed (Android API 27)

Tags: maximo, maximo-anywhere, worklight-runtime

I am getting error as mentioned below while running **./build.sh all** command to build Maximo Anywhere apps.Attached error log.

I have setup everything...worklight console and appcenter console is working fine and I am able to see anywhere runtime in worklight console.

I have installed Java 1.8 and Android API 27.

[Error Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emj8o.png)
[Error Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsLLU.png)

Comment: Please provide details of what you are doing and what you are trying to build. Do you have Android SDK and buildtools path configured? What is beginning of the stack trace? Provide more details.

Comment: Yes I have referenced Android SDK installation path when installing Maximo Anywhere .

Comment: Plz see attached Error Image 1 and Error Image 2 for more details.

Comment: This is not an MFP/ Maximo issue. 
Try the option mentioned in this link:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/solved-android-command-deprecated-error-unable-to-list-target-platforms.458814/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot build an old anywhere version with the new android build tools. Downgrade you api version to 23 and downgrade the android build tools. To downgrade android build tools follow the steps below.

1.Download from the two links below
2. Copy/Unzip the folders to the android studio sdk folder (Replace if prompted)

For Mac OS:
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.2-macosx.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r24.0.3-macosx.zip

For Windows
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.2-windows.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r24.0.3-windows.zip

Comment: Issue fixed after downgrade API version to 24.